# How to convert Longitude and Latitude to points and using the points in drawing a polygon

Tags: java, sql-server, gis, latitude-longitude

I'm new to GIS applications and I have a little problem. I'm trying to plot a polygon using geographic coordinates but I need to convert these coordinates to points before I can use them in plotting the polygon.
I don't know how to convert these coordinates to points to use for the polygon. I spent all my yesterday finding out how to do this but I really still don't get it.
I tried using the geography datatype in ms sql server 2008 but I couldn't find a java api in retrieving the polygon or the converted coordinates.
Please help me with a sample code on how to do this.

Thanks a lot people!!!

This is my code. 'Code'

```
double earth=6371;
double focal=500;

double lat= 47.653 ;
double lon = -122.358  ;

double latitude = lat*Math.PI/180;
double longitude = lon*Math.PI/180;

double x = earth * Math.sin(latitude)*Math.cos(longitude);

double y = earth * Math.sin(latitude)*Math.sin(longitude);

double z = earth * Math.cos(latitude);

double projectedX = x*focal /(focal+z);

double projectedY = y * focal / (focal+z);

int magx = (int) Math.round(projectedX * 5); 
int magy = (int) Math.round(projectedY *5);

System.out.println ("MAG X : "+magx);
System.out.println ("MAG Y : "+magy);
```

I just plug in d mag x and y into my polygon but nothing comes up.

Comment: Searching on keywords from the title i.e. 'convert Longitude Latitude points polygon' reveals a lot of likely hits, many of them on SO.  Why not investigate those and try to cut some code, instead of effectively asking people to spoon-feed solutions to you?

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounds like I want to be spoonfed. But honestly, I've done a lot of research on this. A Simple explanation is all I need and somewhere I could post questions on the problem and get directions.

Comment: *"But honestly, I've done a lot of research on this."*  But link to the threads & stop expecting us to rely on the honesty of some random stranger who has just joined this site (checks) today.  **More importantly,** it also has the benefit of showing us what you looked at, and helping us to understand why they were not suitable for this use-case.  Surprising as it may seem, the folks at SO are not psychic (well most of them aren't, anyway). *"A Simple explanation is all I need"* I'd bet there are many in the pages you didn't link to.  SO is not a 'tutor me' site.

Comment: Hello andrew. I tried converting longitude and latitude to points using this code I found on SO but I don't know if I'm doing it right cos the polygon doesn't plot anything. This is my code. I'm using a phone so please excuse me if I don't use the code tag. 'Code'

Answer (score 2):

This is the syntax for creating and retrieving a geography Polygon in SQL Server from a set of *n* coordinates:

```
DECLARE @Polygon geography;
SET @Polygon = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((Lon1 Lat1, Lon2 Lat2, ... Lonn Latn, Lon1 Lat1))', 4326); 
SELECT @Polygon;
```

(This assumes you're using geographic coordinates relative to the WGS84 datum. If you don't know what that means, they probably are.)

Comment: Thank you. I can display the data on my mssql studio. I want to view that same polygon in a java application, don't know if that's possible.

Comment: Yes - connect to the database via JDBC, execute a stored procedure to retrieve the results you want, and then plot them in Java. Java won't understand SQL Server's native geography format, so use ToString() in your query to return the results as text-based WKT instead. You can then parse the string of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you. I tried retrieving the data from the geography column in bytes then I converted it to string but the output does not make any sense cos its still in the unreadable byte format..

Comment: Don't retrieve it in bytes - retrieve it as a *string* using ToString() and then parse the string.

Comment: I retrieved it using String a = resultSet.getString("location"); but parsing it to the polygon give me errors. I used polygon.addPoint(a); but its nt accepting the values.